# PHP query not finding anything.. Am i doing something wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been trying to figure out what's going wrong here. I'm sending POST data from my android app. Username and a password. Both encoded. My php file receives the post data trough a HTTP call, I've tested this and read the data being sent and it's 100% correct.

---

Through my app, I send Admin : Admin. The database connected with the script has a single row populated with the same results Username : Admin, Password : Admin.

In my PHP code, I've created three checks. RowCount 1 (Found one result)?

```
        if ($num_rows == 1)
    {
        $totalData["success"] = 1;
        $totalData["message"] = "Logged in successfully.";
        echo json_encode($totalData);
    }
```

Rowcount 0 (found nothing)

```
        elseif ($num_rows == 0)
    {
        $totalData["success"] = 0;
        $totalData["message"] = "Could not find user. Please check your username and/or password.";
        echo json_encode($totalData);
    }
```

And an else (which is never called, because there's always either 0 or 1 result(s)). I put this in for testing purposes.

```
        else
    {
        $totalData["success"] = 3;
        $totalData["message"] = "No data found. fix your shit.";
        echo json_encode($totalData);
    }
```

I'm expecting to get the first part back, if num_rows == 1. Admin : Admin exists, so it should hook to that if statement. The problem is, it's not doing that. It gives me the elseif statement. It hasn't found a single result in my database with the values of Admin:Admin.

I'll return the data set in the post (sent through my app) to show you that it's valid data.

JSON data returned by script.

```
04-26 20:59:52.099    2984-3000/com.wachisu.insertapp V/userInserter﹕ {"message":"Could not find user. Please check your username and\/or password.","isSuccess":0,"sesUsername":"admin","sesPassword":"admin","sesDB":"user1","success":0}
```

---

I've put together the following script :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password']) && isset($_POST['Database']))
{
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $database = $_POST['Database'];
    $totalData = array(
        "message" => "",
        "isSuccess" => 0,
        "sesUsername" => $username,
        "sesPassword" => $password,
        "sesDB" => $database
    );
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user1', 'root', '');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $checkUsers = "SELECT
                        username, password
                    FROM
                        users
                    WHERE
                        username = :username
                    AND
                        password = :password";
        $userStmt = $db->prepare($checkUsers);
        $userStmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $username,
            ':password' => $password
        ));
        $user = $userStmt->fetchAll();
        $num_rows = count($user);
        if ($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $totalData["success"] = 1;
            $totalData["message"] = "Logged in successfully.";
            echo json_encode($totalData);
        }
        elseif ($num_rows == 0)
        {
            $totalData["success"] = 0;
            $totalData["message"] = "Could not find user. Please check your username and/or password.";
            echo json_encode($totalData);
        }
        else
        {
            $totalData["success"] = 3;
            $totalData["message"] = "No data found. fix your shit.";
            echo json_encode($totalData);
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $message = $e->getMessage();
    }

    $db = NULL;
}
```

I keep trying to send the username : admin, password : admin.

My database looks as follows :

[image: Database screenshot]

I just know that I'm overlooking something, something minor. My brain somewhat gave up.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Screenshots are not an ideal way to present a database structure - the best way is to issue `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and to paste the result into the question.

Comment: On top of the above, you are storing your passwords as plain text?  Don't do that.

Comment: Ofcourse not. Well, yes, but,  all that i'm trying to do is test HTTP connections between my application and my PHP script/Database. I'm well aware of the need to hash and salt my passwords. This is a test application, nothing that goes beyond my local wamp map.

Comment: What HTTP response does your app get? I can't see what the actual problem is (I assume you are getting one response but expecting another).

Comment: I'm sending Admin : Admin to the script, as the database is populated with Admin : Admin, it should return if ($num_rows == 1)
        {
            $totalData["success"] = 1;
            $totalData["message"] = "Logged in successfully.";
            echo json_encode($totalData);
        },                     now it's simply returning that it hasn't found anything. So admin : admin doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, add that to your question please (formatted if you would). In terms of debugging, have you tried sending back a JSON reply containing all of `print_r($_POST)`? Maybe you are using an incorrect fieldname (e.g. `username` instead of `Username`)?

Comment: (When replying to me please use @halfer otherwise I may miss your reply).

Comment: @halfer , how does this look?

Comment: Hmm, your `$num_rows` comes from a manual count - I wonder if your `execute()` failed? Try running the statement in your database manually, and if that works, add error handling to the execute code. I believe this returns a boolean success value (check the manual, of course).

Comment: @halfer , haven't worked with SQL for quite some time now. " select username and password from users where username = "admin" and password = "admin" " seems to bring back nothing. No results. That's the problem! Thank you for pointing that out <3

Comment: You may have accidentally added spaces to your strings in your database - pleased it is now working. Don't forgot to take @nomistic's advice - passwords need to be strongly hashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see in your post you don't care about data.

But it could be data issue.

So you wrote *Username : Admin, Password : Admin*

And you've present us screenshot with **Username : admin, Password : admin** in your database.

So did you really checked good data when post?

it SHOULD BE lower case : `admin`, `admin`.

**EDIT 1**

Looking to the new screenshot from phpMyAdmin , I have another guess about your column name `password`. It seems MySQL recognize *password* as a keyword, not a column name. To fix that you should use backticks around that field name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE
  username = 'admin'
  AND
  `password` = 'admin'
```

Comment: Indeed, it's a typo in the explanation. I've done manual queries which yield the same results, 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, my database was the problem. Nothing could be selected. I created a new database with the exact same  values and it DID work. Thank you to everyone who tried to help!

[image: Database]